# How to Run Java Module class (java 9 jigsaw project) with third party library (jar files)?

Tags: java, java-9, java-module, java-platform-module-system, module-path

Right now I'm trying to develop a Java project with pure java (no builtscript). I'm implementing the module concept from Java 9. I'm having a trouble when it comes to run a Java project (main class) with additional jar file (third party library). I have no trouble when compiling but when I try to run the java it couldn't run as expected.

I could compile this project by executing this command (javaFiles.txt contains my java files that wanted to be compiled):

```
javac --module-path lib -d newout --module-source-path src @javaFiles.txt
```

But when I try to run the compiled .class file with this command:

```
java --module-path newout;libs --module com.example.trial/com.example.trial.CreateProduct
```

I got this error as if it's a wrong command:

```
$ java --module-path newout;libs --module com.example.trial/com.example.trial.CreateProduct
Usage: java [options] <mainclass> [args...]
       (to execute a class) or  java [options] -jar <jarfile> [args...]
       (to execute a jar file)
...
```

I'm using ubuntu. Is there any other way to do it?

And also I don't really know the differences between classpath, modulepath and whatsoever. I always try to run this from module path.

I got some references from [this link](https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/core-java-tutorial/modules/automatic-modules.html) and [this link](https://developer.ibm.com/technologies/java/tutorials/java-modularity-5/). Those two tells me the command that I've mentioned above.

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The path separator in all non-Windows systems is colon (`:`), not semicolon (`;`).  You need to change this:

```
java --module-path newout;libs
```

to this:

```
java --module-path newout:libs
```

Unix shells use `;` to separate two consecutive commands.  So your original line was actually trying to execute these two commands:

```
$ java --module-path newout
$ libs --module com.example.trial/com.example.trial.CreateProduct
```

Comment: thank you so much! works like a charm. :) didn't know those things exist before.. thank you very much once again

Comment: I remember this being mentioned explicitly in one of the oracle migration documents. (tools documentation possibly).